# PHP regex get bracket conflict

Tags: php, regex

So i got this:

```
$output = "bla bla {_here I am (lots of things) can happen here! it's ok} bla bla";
@preg_match_all('/.*{_([^}]*)}/',$output, $conditions);
```

The result is as expected until we have multiple brackets. 
I want to get the content of the string :

```
$output = "bla bla {_here I am (lots of things) {conflict} can happen here! it's ok} bla bla"    
@preg_match_all('/.*{_([^}]*)}/',$output, $conditions);
```

I want to get content between brackets that correspond to one another
Result should be like this:

```
1. {_here I am (lots of things) {conflict} can happen here! it's ok}
2. {conflict}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, regular expressions are not a particularly good choice for parsing recursive patterns and I would recommend against using them.

If you *know* that your input can only have two levels of brackets, a pattern like this would be sufficient:

```
/{_[^{}]*(?:({[^{}]*})[^{}]*)*}/
```

For example:

```
$output = "bla bla {_here I am (lots of things) {conflict} can happen here! it's ok} bla bla";
preg_match('/{_[^{}]*(?:({[^{}]*})[^{}]*)*}/',$output, $conditions);
```

However, PHP does have extensions to support [recursive patterns](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.recursive.php). For example:

```
$output = "bla bla {_here I am (lots of things) {conflict} can happen here! it's ok} bla bla";
preg_match('/{(?:[^{}]*|((?R)))*}/',$output, $conditions);
```

Both of the above samples will produce:

```
Array
(
    [0] => {_here I am (lots of things) {conflict} can happen here! it's ok}
    [1] => {conflict}
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have more than 1 level nesting, you can use this pattern:

```
preg_match('~(?=({(?>[^{}]++|(?1))*}))/',$output, $conditions);
```

This pattern, that uses recursion (`(?1)` is an alias of the capturing group 1), will give you all overlapping results since it is embedded in a lookahead assertion.